# How can I view a static variable from outside the function that defines it in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am looking at a crash dump, and an important clue to how this crash occurred may be inside the value of a static variable (an integer in this case) inside a function. The problem is that the function with that static variable is is not in my call stack where the crash occurred so I can't just look at it directly. Is there a way to view the contents of this variable from the debugger from outside the function that declares it?

Edit:

Sample code has been requested

```
int funcitonWithStaticVar()
{
    static int iRetVal;
    if (iRetVal == 0)
    {
        iRetVal = initializeValue();
    }
    return iRetVal
}

void functionThatCrashes()
{
    // Crash occurs in this function. The 
    // static variable in the other function 
    // may hold an important clue as to why
}

int foo()
{
    functionWithStaticVar();
    functionThatCrashes();
}
```

Comment: Can you add a piece of example code so that I'm clear on exactly what's going on?

Comment: I thought the explanation was enough, but I added sample code. Does that clear it up?

Comment: If you disassemble the function that contains the static variable, you should be able to figure out its address from the code in that function that manipulates it.

Comment: @caf, Looks like viewing the disassembly was the way to go. If you put that down as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the address of the static variable by viewing the disassembly of the function that accesses it.